# Heap corruption detected due to array usage

Tags: c++, arrays, heap-memory

Sorry, I'm a brand new newbie to C++ and programming and I'm getting a heap corruption error. I think Im writing in unallocated memory but I can't seem to find where the error is... the program is soppuse to take user input values and rearrange them so that they would ascend. I'm also learning templates too.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void sort(T arrayz[], int size, char ch)
{
    T temporary;
    int k, j;

    if (ch = 'a')
    {
        for (k = 0; k < size; k++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                temporary = arrayz[j];
                arrayz[j] = arrayz[j + 1];
                arrayz[j + 1] = temporary;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int choices, range, i;
    int x;
    char ch;

    cout << ("Enter the amount of numbers you want =>");
    cin >> x;

    int *numbers = new int[x];
    if (!numbers)
    {
        cout << "Memory Allocation error!";
        cin.get();
        exit(1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<x; i++)
    {
        cout << "Option number" << i + 1 << " =>";
        cin >> numbers[i];
    }

    cout << "Do you want ascending or descending values (a/d) =>" ;
    cin >> ch;

    if (ch = 'a')
    {
        sort(numbers, x, ch);
    }

    else if (ch = 'd')
    {
        sort(numbers, x, ch);
    }

    delete[] numbers;
    fflush(stdin);
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Assigning to arrayz[j + 1] corrupts the heap, the for loop has an off-by-one bug.  Google "c bubble sort".

Comment: `if (ch = 'a')`  This should be `if (ch == 'a')`

Comment: Whyz do you add z to the endz of your wordz?

Answer (score 1):

In your `sort` function, you are accessing elements at index `j + 1`. However, this is out of bounds. The valid indexes for your `arrayz` array are `0` through `size-1`. When `j` is `size-1`, `j+1` is `size`, which accesses past the end of the array.